# FactoryGirl: Assigning a value of false to a boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

In my Factory I have a boolean field (evaluated), which I am trying to set to false. I want the field to be required, and always set to either **true** or **false**

Model

```
  validates_presence_of :evaluated
```

Factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :submission do
    evaluated true
    score 1.5
    ranking 1.5
    submission_type "user"
    .
    .
  end
end
```

In the test

```
    it { should validate_presence_of(:evaluated) }
```

When I run it

```
     Failure/Error: expect(@submission).to be_valid
   expected #<Submission id: nil, competition_id: 163, user_id: 134, team_id: nil, evaluated: false, score: 1.5, ranking: 1.5, submission_type_cd: "user", withdrawn: true, withdrawn_date: "2016-02-08", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to be valid, but got errors: Evaluated can't be blank
```

If I change the value to true, the test passes

```
    evaluated true
```

How can I set up a Factory with false values for Booleans?

Comment: It's more that you can't validate the presence of booleans. `false.present? => false`

Comment: So the best option is to add it as not null at the db level?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd do

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would rather use `inclusion_of` validation instead of `presence` validation.

From the rails [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_presence_of),

If you want to validate the presence of a boolean field (where the real values are true and false), you will want to use

`validates_inclusion_of :field_name, in: [true, false]`

This is due to the way `Object#blank?` handles boolean values

i.e `false.blank? # => true`

Then your test would be something like,

`it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:field_name).in_array([true, false]) }`